# How to match a one of a set of numbers?

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a group of numbers in regex that consist of one of the following:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

But I am having trouble figuring out the regex.

For single digits this pattern worked fine "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9" but it fails on double digit numbers. For example 12 passes as ok due to the regex finding the 1 in 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if you want to check if just **one** number is between *0 and 11*.

```
^[0-9]$|^1?[0-1]$
```

If you want to match a string like:

```
1,2,3,12,32,5,1,6,8, 11
```

and match 0-11 then you can use the following:

```
(?<=,|^)([0-9]|1?[0-1])(?=,|$)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use begin and end anchors to force the whole string to be matched:

```
^(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11)$
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
^(\d|10|11)$
```

Comment: This will not work, if you going to match `^` and `$` you also need to match the `,`'s

Comment: @sQVe: I think the OP has a single number, not a comma-delimited list.

Comment: @Cameron - that is right - I was trying to match one number of of the possible inputs of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 minus the commas.

Comment: @sQVe - I was using regex in c# as it was a more elegant solution rather than a separate function :)

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `^(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|(10)|(11))$`

Comment: @malovern Regex can be more compact: `^[0-9]$|^1?[0-1]$`, see my answer.